# Excel - Using SQL command on Power Query data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, sql, power-query, salesforce

Using Power Query, I pull in two reports from Salesforce using `Power Query > Get external Data > From Online Services`.
I load them into tables in two different sheets, and then create a third worksheet and table using `Data > Get external Data > From other sources > From MS Query > From Excel` referencing the workbook itself.

Now I can change the SQL Command text under `Connection Properties` and reference the Salesforce reports by using the Worksheet they're in (e.g. `[Sheet2$]`)

I am successfully able to change my Salesforce reports online and have the change show up in my Excel, and using SQL, I can do things with the data in a way that I'm familiar with.

My question: Can I do the same thing, without loading the Salesforce reports into worksheets? Without MS Query'ing the woorkbook itself?

Comment: Have you tried not loading the source data into Excel and simply making a connection in Power Query?

Comment: @Sudachi If I don't load the data into Excel, and just make the connection, I don't know how to access the data in my SQL command text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would uncheck the **Enable Load** option on your 2 Salesforce Queries (from the right-click menu). This will stop loading their data into an Excel table.

Then I would rebuild your 3rd Query, starting from a **Reference** to one of the Salesforce Queries (right-click menu). Then in that Query's steps, you can combine data from the other Salesforce Query by adding **Merge** or **Append** Steps.

The transformation steps available in the Power Query ribbon cover everything you can do using SQL and much more.